# Removing a JavaScript comment through commands?

Tags: comments

I am currently developing a website that relies heavily on large blocks of javascript for widgets. Some of these are demanding processes, such as running timers or clocks, so I only want these scripts to activate when their corresponding widget is activated. My proposed solution is to comment out each of these blocks of scripts, and "uncomment" them when the widget is active.

For example, if I have a countdown timer widget, I would like to have my code for the widget completely commented out until the user clicks the widget. When the user opens the widget, I would like the corresponding scripts to become "uncommented" and execute.

Is there any way I can programmatically add or remove comment marks to the Javascript code on the fly? I am looking for some method or command I could use; not something that requires me to physically alter the code.

I saw this in a Google I/O Conference Presentation, so I was just wondering if anyone knew how.

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this. (Plus it's impossible)

Comment: A direct answer to your question? No, you cannot modify JavaScript source code using JavaScript.

Comment: I'm totally aware. I actually just saw a Google I/O Conference. They apparently use this for the GMail compose button, so I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way to go about it. If you're worried about clogging the event loop: make sure widgets don't have access to the event loop but have to go through your framework to get to it. This allows you to 'sleep' a widget, stop all it's events.

Another thing to keep in mind that is that when widgets are removed you must also clean up any events they have scheduled or you will run into 'dead' code. All events must therefor be scheduled through your framework so you can clean them up if the widget is unloaded.

---

Code is read and loaded into the JavaScript engine, modifying the code after that point will do nothing.

Comment: I'm aware that this isn't the best way to deal with the performance issues, but I was just wondering if it was possible to alter the comments in the source code like this. Thanks though!